# Scripts not loading in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to load scripts in Wordpress functions.php and they are not loading.

functions.php

```
        <!--====== Jquery js ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <!--====== Bootstrap js ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <!--====== Slick js ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/slick.min.js"></script>
        <!--====== Magnific Popup js ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <!--====== Isotope js ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <!--====== Imagesloaded js ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <!--====== nice-select js ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
        <!--====== select number ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/jquery.nice-number.min.js"></script>
        <!--====== jquery-ui js  ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <!--====== Syotimer js  ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/jquery.syotimer.min.js"></script>
        <!--====== Main js ======-->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/main.js"></script>

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

They aren't loading and I need to get this working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using wp_enqueue_scripts to instruct WP to load the 'add_scripts' function. But where is your `function add_scripts()` ??  --- Please refer to the hook [offical_reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/)

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote will not work, you should use the `wp_enqueue_script` function for this.
and instead of using `bloginfo('template_directory')` use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` as mentioned [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/)

you can use the below example to load the scripts in your website.

```
function load_my_script_files(){
  wp_enqueue_script('modrenizer', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-3.6.0.min.js", array(), "3.6.0");
  // Add lines like the one above to add other scripts, if one script is dependent on the other put its name inside the array()
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_script_files' );
```

If you want to know more about how this works I reccomend reading the developer documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: I did what you said and wrote this code but it still isn't loading the js unless I put it In the footer.php.

```function load_my_script_files(){

    wp_enqueue_script('modrenizer', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-3.6.0.min.js", array(), "3.6.0");
  }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_script_files' );```

Comment: you have to add a line of  ` wp_enqueue_script` for every JavaScript you want to load. jquery, bootstrap, etc.